# Why is Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject adding "_repository" to each item in my list?

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have a simple method that looks like this:

```
public partial class PEUploadBookHistory: DataAccessBase
{
    public string Get()
    {
        List<PEUploadBookHistory> histories = _repository.GetList<PEUploadBookHistory>().ToList();
        string jsonHistories = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(histories);
        return jsonHistories;
    }
    
    // Other methods like Post and Put, etc
}
```

And `_repository.GetList` is a Dapper repository:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetList<T>()
{
    IEnumerable<T> entities;
    using (var connection = OpenConnection(_connectionStringName))
    {
        entities = connection.GetList<T>();
    }
    return entities;
}
```

The json string that is returned by the first method looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "_repository": {},
    "UploadBookHistoryId": 5467,
    ... other properties ...
  }
]
```

I don't understand why it's adding `"_repository": {},`.  Shouldn't that be `PEUploadBookHistory`? Where is that coming from? Why? And how do I change it?

Here's the rest of the partial:

```
[Table("PE_UploadBookHistory")]
public partial class PEUploadBookHistory
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int UploadBookHistoryId { get; set; }
    ... other columns ...
}
```

And here's `DataAccessBase`

```
public class DataAccessBase
{
    public Repository _repository = new Repository("SQLConnection");
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the definition of `PEUploadBookHistory`?

Comment: done. Thank you :)

Comment: Nothing there stands out, but it's a partial class.  Is there another part of the definition someplace?  Does your code contain "_repository" anywhere?  It's behaving like there's a public property or field named `_repository`.  That's the most likely explanation... if that's not it, then I'm really not sure.

Comment: Ah, your `connection.GetList<T>();` call must be returning an object that contains that property.  I had assumed that you were getting a `List<T>` but that isn't the case.

Comment: Thanks Amy.  I edited the OP to show that.  Maybe start from the top again.

Comment: `connection.GetList<T>();` is just Dapper. Straight outa the box.

Comment: Last question:  Are you able to modify `DataAccessBase`?  That is, it's your code?

Comment: Yes, that's my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decorate this property with `JsonIgnore`:

```
[JsonIgnore]
public Repository _repository = new Repository("SQLConnection");
```

Alternatively, you can make it non-public.

Alternatively, use different models for database and JSON.

If neither of those solutions will work, you can use a custom Json contract class, which will take a bit more work to put together.

Comment: if I made it non-public, what would it be?  private? sealed? I'm getting other problems with both.

Comment: By default Newtonsoft serializes only public properties.  You can try `protected` or `internal`, though I'm not sure if Newtonsoft handles internal props.

Comment: Actually, non issue!  `[JsonIgnore]` worked.  Thanks!